How to determine IS_DEBUG in compose mutliplatform
how to determine IS_DEBUG in compose multiplatform in commonMain?. BuildKonfig and gmazzo/buildconfig don't help.
If you know, please give instructions)
Code:
this code does not work
`buildConfig {
    buildConfigField("Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", provider {project.findProperty("isDebug")?.toString() ?: false})

}`
buildConfigField("Boolean", "IS_DEBUG", "how to determine IS_DEBUG here or elsewhere)`

https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig, or define expect/actual for each platform
